# Save Spyder console output containing figures

Tags: python, pdf, plot, save, spyder

I have lots of plot results output in Spyder console. Is there any easy way to save these results in a big file such as pdf etc. Currently I have to manually copy each of the plot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You can save all console output to an Html file, by doing right click on it and selecting the option called `Save as HTML/XML`, as shown below:

[image: context-menu]

Comment: Is there any python function to do this programatically?

Comment: @UtkarshPanwar have you managed to do it?
I need to do the same as a python function.

Comment: @innuendo, there's no way to do this programatically, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using matplotlib, this is the solution:

```
#importing libraries
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#just making a plot for an example
y = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
x = np.arange(10)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, label='$y = numbers')
plt.title('Legend inside')
ax.legend()
#plt.show()

#The saving part of the solution
fig.savefig('plot.png')
```

To change the format, simply change the extension like so:

```
fig.savefig('plot.pdf')
```

or

```
fig.savefig("plot.pdf", format='pdf', dpi=1000, bbox_inches='tight')
```

source: [Matplotlib save figure to image file](https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-save-figure-to-image-file/)

please, provide your code for more help.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I ran into this issue and found a nifty matplotlib backend method that allows for multiple figures to be saved as different pages in a pdf file. You can use the figure objects or just their number/name. Here is the code I wrote to do it.

```
#==============================================================================
# Imports
#==============================================================================
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#==============================================================================
# Functions
#==============================================================================

def pdf_save(fig_list, file_name, path_name='/path_name/'):

  pp=PdfPages(path_name+file_name)
  for fig in fig_list:
    pp.savefig(figure=fig)

  pp.close()

  print 'PDF saved to %s' % path_name+file_name
  return


#==============================================================================
# Run as main script (testing purposes) 
#==============================================================================

if (__name__ == "__main__" ) and 0:
  plt.close('all')

  y=np.array([0,1])

  f1=plt.figure()
  plt.plot(y)
  f2=plt.figure()
  plt.plot(-y)
  plt.figure()
  plt.plot(2*y)

  pdf_save([f1,f2,3], 'test_pdf_save.pdf')
```